# JQuery set selected option based on partial match of value

Tags: jquery

I have a select full of options with email addresses as values, like so:

```
   <select id="employee-email">
    <option value="employee1@employer.com">Employee Name</option>
    <option value="employee2@employer.com">Employee Name</option>
    <option value="employee3@employer.com">Employee Name</option>
   </select>
```

I have a variable called `email`. Based on this email, I would like to select the corresponding employee name. This works if the email address is an exact match, e.g

```
 var email = 'employee1@employer.com';
 $("#employee-email option[value='" + email + "']").attr("selected", true);
```

But `email` could be from any one of many different domains- it could be `employee1@employer.com`, `employee1@employer.de`, `employee1@employer.co.uk`, but it will always correspond to the same employee. So what I want to do is split the string to e.g `employee1` and select the option based on this. Unfortunately the `value=` selector doesn't work for a partial match. Can anyone suggest how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

split the email on `@`, then use `shift()` to get the first part, the employee, then use that in the attribute starts with selector to get the option starting with a value matching the employee, and set it as selected

```
var email = 'employee1@employer.com';
$("#employee-email option[value^='" + email.split('@').shift() + "']").prop("selected", true);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/C7uh7/)

Comment: Ah, the handy "starts with" selector saves the day again. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

here is an function example how to get the email address unti the '@' sign.

it gets the email address and returns only the string until the '@'.

so u can do like this

```
var email = cutEmail(tempEmail);
// your code

//the function to cut the string
function cutEmail(email){
    str ='';
    for(i=0;i<email.length; i++){
        if(email.charAt(i)== '@'){
             break;
        }
        str+= email.charAt(i);
    }
    return(str);
}
```